# Open Source Quantum Algorithm Development projects

Tags: quantum-algorithms, resource-request

Is there a platform where people contribute together to solving tasks in the area of quantum algorithm development?

Comment: Maybe GitHub? Also Qiskit library contain many open source implementation of quantum algorithms.

Comment: It seems to me that [Quantum Computing Stack Exchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) is one such platform.